# Dijkstra's Algorithm with directed graph java

Tags: java, algorithm, dijkstra

I am trying learn and implement Dijkstra's algorithm for directed graphs in JAVA, I found this piece of code through Stackoverflow.

http://en.literateprograms.org/index.php?title=Special%3aDownloadCode/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm_%28Java%29&oldid=15444

I understand some stuff, but I am having difficulty on figuring out which way to go for these two questions?

1) The number of trips starting at A and ending at A with a maximum of 3 stops. (Does this mean I find the route from A - A ? Because that always comes to 0.

And this: 
The distance of the route A-E-B-C-D - (Should I call the compute for each node and then add them all up ? Is this the smartest way ? )

Here is my code: 
Any Help would be appreciated.

My Output is:

Distance to A: 0.0
Path: [A]
Distance to B: 5.0
Path: [A, B]
Distance to C: 9.0
Path: [A, B, C]
Distance to D: 5.0
Path: [A, D]
Distance to E: 7.0
Path: [A, E]

package src.main.java;

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex>
{
    public final String name;
    public Edge[] adjacencies;
    public double minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    public Vertex previous;
    public Vertex(String argName) { name = argName; }
    public String toString() { return name; }
    public int compareTo(Vertex other)
    {
        return Double.compare(minDistance, other.minDistance);
    }

}


class Edge
{
    public final Vertex target;
    public final double weight;
    public Edge(Vertex argTarget, double argWeight)
    { target = argTarget; weight = argWeight; }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void computePaths(Vertex source)
    {
        source.minDistance = 0.;
        PriorityQueue<Vertex> vertexQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
        vertexQueue.add(source);

        while (!vertexQueue.isEmpty()) {
            Vertex u = vertexQueue.poll();

            // Visit each edge exiting u
            for (Edge e : u.adjacencies)
            {
                Vertex v = e.target;
                double weight = e.weight;
                double distanceThroughU = u.minDistance + weight;
                if (distanceThroughU < v.minDistance) {
                    vertexQueue.remove(v);

                    v.minDistance = distanceThroughU ;
                    v.previous = u;
                    vertexQueue.add(v);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<Vertex> getShortestPathTo(Vertex target)
    {
        List<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        for (Vertex vertex = target; vertex != null; vertex = vertex.previous)
            path.add(vertex);

        Collections.reverse(path);
        return path;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Vertex v0 = new Vertex("A");
        Vertex v1 = new Vertex("B");
        Vertex v2 = new Vertex("C");
        Vertex v3 = new Vertex("D");
        Vertex v4 = new Vertex("E");
        v0.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v1,  5),
                new Edge(v3,  5), new Edge(v4, 7) };
        v1.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v2,  4)};
        v2.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v3,  8), new Edge(v4, 2) };
        v3.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v2, 8),
                new Edge(v4,  6) };
        v4.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v1, 3) };

        Vertex[] vertices = { v0, v1, v2, v3, v4};

        computePaths(v0);
        for (Vertex v : vertices)
        {
            System.out.println("Distance to " + v + ": " + v.minDistance);
            List<Vertex> path = getShortestPathTo(v);
            System.out.println("Path: " + path);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What don't you understand? A-A distance will always be 0, won't it?

Comment: Thanks for responding @MateuszKwasniak I have edited my question to better reflect my confusion.